# Python error while using MysqlDb - sets module is deprecated

Tags: python, mysql

I'm currently getting the warning every time I run a Python script that uses MySQLdb:

```
/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/MySQLdb/__init__.py:34:
DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import ImmutableSet
```

I'd rather not mess with their lib if possible. I'm on Ubuntu server. Anyone know an easy way to fix that warning message?

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
Fixed it based on the suggestions below and this link: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=505611

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*the sets module is deprecated.*',
                        DeprecationWarning, 'MySQLdb')
import MySQLdb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this before the mysql module is imported

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", message='the sets module is deprecated')
import sets
```

Comment: Please ignore DeprecationWarnings from the MySQLdb module instead, or you might ignore uses of the sets module you *do* control, or other types of warnings that have matching text.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the warning using the [`warnings`](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings) module, or the `-W` argument to Python. Don't ignore all `DeprecationWarnings`, though, just the ones from `MySQLdb` :)

Comment: thanks Thomas, how would I ignore the ones just from mysqldb?

Comment: You pass the right module as the `module` argument to the warnings filter.

Answer (score 0):

All it means is the sets module (more specifically the immutableset part) is deprecated, and you should use it's replacement, set. Set is inbuilt so no need to import.

If you need an immutable set, [frozenset()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't his code that's using the sets module.

Comment: hi Dominic.. thanks for the reply. Its the mysqldb library so I don't want to go changing their codebase unless I have to. any ideas?